# as dynamic texts with jquery validate?

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

I have been researching and found there a code to generate dynamic text fields as my situation is that validate these fields before sending them via array and specify the user and are not added anything numbers.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var max_fields = Infinity; //maximum input boxes allowed
  var wrapper1 = $(".input_fields_wrap1");
  var add_button1 = $(".add_field_button1"); //Add button

  var x = 1; //initlal text box count
  $(add_button1).click(function(e) { //on add input button click
    e.preventDefault();
    if (x < max_fields) { //max input box allowed
      x++; //text box increment
      $(wrapper1).append('<div>Product <input type="text" name="Product[]"/> Price <input type="text" name="Price[]"/>  Quantity <input type="text" name="Quantity[]"/><a href="#" class="remove_field">Remove</a></div>'); //add input box
    }
  });

  $(wrapper1).on("click", ".remove_field", function(e) { //user click on remove text
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).parent('div').remove();
    x--;
  })


});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label for="PASIVOS">Data Enter</label>
<div class="input_fields_wrap1">
  <input class="add_field_button1" type="button" value="+ Add" />
</div>
```

I'm not very good with jquery what I want is to show an alert to the pair of the text field that says that the field is required.

Comment: accomplish something but only the first input validates me and others that do not generate could help me

http://jsfiddle.net/sarrhen/6cuu4rpw/

Answer (score 0):

Correct me if I'm wrong here, but are you asking how to make sure the user will put in numbers on some of your text fields? If so you can just use [jquery's `.isNumeric()` function](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.isNumeric/), like so:

```
if(element1.isNumeric() && element2.isNumeric()){
    //do what you want to do
....
```

Another option is to use regex, as in:

```
var re = /^\d+$/;
if(re.test(element1)) { //test whether element1 is an int
   //do what you want to do
....
```

Comment: I'm not very good with jquery what I want is to show an alert to the pair of the text field that says that the field is required

Comment: but as validate the input text when generated at least I need to say that eson required fields

Answer (score 0):

```
accomplish something but only the first input validates me and others that do not generate could help me

http://jsfiddle.net/sarrhen/6cuu4rpw/
```